# DataFrame to dictionary with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have this small dataframe:

```
SUB_PROCEDURE   ZFIELD  ZFIELD2 ZVALUE_ENABLED
----------------------------------------------
          SP1        A      ZF1            ZV1
          SP1        A      ZF2            ZV2
          SP1        B      ZF3            ZV3
          SP1        B      ZF4            ZV4
          SP2        A      NaN            ZV5
          SP2        A      NaN            ZV6
```

I would like to obtain this dictionary from it:

```
desired_output = {
    'A': {
        'SP1': {'ZF1': 'ZV1', 'ZF2': 'ZV2'},
        'SP2': ['ZV5', 'ZV6']
    },
    'B': {
        'SP1': {'ZF3': 'ZV3', 'ZF4': 'ZV4'},
        'SP2': None
    }
}
```

The rules would be:

1. Create a key value pair for each distinct zfield in the dataframe. See rule 2 for the value.
2. In the above value, create a key value pair for each sub_procedure. See rule 3 for the value.
3. If ZFIELD2 is NaN, then concatenate in a list the different ZVALUE_ENABLED. If ZFIELD2 is not NaN, then create a key value pair for each combination of ZFIELD2 and ZVALUE_ENABLED.
4. If there's no entry for that ZFIELD and SUB_PROCEDURE for SP1 or SP2 (configurable), then display key: None.

So far, I've been trying with default dictionaries and this [answer] ([Pandas dataframe to dictionary with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70678968/pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary-with-conditions/70679119#70679119))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with custom function for dictionaries or lists if all values in `ZFIELD2` are missing values, for add `None`s is used [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), replaced `NaN`s to `None`s in [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and last is used [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
def f(x):
    return dict(x[['ZFIELD2','ZVALUE_ENABLED']].to_numpy()) 
           if x['ZFIELD2'].notna().all() 
           else x['ZVALUE_ENABLED'].tolist()

df = df.groupby(['SUB_PROCEDURE','ZFIELD']).apply(f).unstack()
out = df.mask(df.isna(), None).to_dict()
print (out)
{'A': {'SP1': {'ZF1': 'ZV1', 'ZF2': 'ZV2'},
       'SP2': ['ZV5', 'ZV6']}, 
 'B': {'SP1': {'ZF3': 'ZV3', 'ZF4': 'ZV4'},
       'SP2': None}}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the DataFrame values to a numpy array and iterate over them in a for loop. In the loop using `dict.setdefault`, collect the row items in a nested dictionary structure.

```
out = {}
for w, x, y, z in df.iloc[:,[1,0,2,3]].to_numpy():
    out.setdefault(w, {})
    if pd.notna(y):
        out[w].setdefault(x, {})[y] = z
    else:
        out[w].setdefault(x, []).append(z)
```

This produces

```
{'A': {'SP1': {'ZF1': 'ZV1', 'ZF2': 'ZV2'}, 'SP2': ['ZV5', 'ZV6']},
 'B': {'SP1': {'ZF3': 'ZV3', 'ZF4': 'ZV4'}}}
```

Now you want to add `SP2` key inside `B` key. To do that, iterate over the unique values of `df['SUB_PROCEDURE']` and for each key-value pair in `out` see if a sub-procedure key is missing and if it is, add that key in.

```
for sp in df['SUB_PROCEDURE'].unique():
    for k, v in out.items():
        v.setdefault(sp, None)
```

Final output:

```
{'A': {'SP1': {'ZF1': 'ZV1', 'ZF2': 'ZV2'}, 'SP2': ['ZV5', 'ZV6']},
 'B': {'SP1': {'ZF3': 'ZV3', 'ZF4': 'ZV4'}, 'SP2': None}}
```